# Data Templating with user input fields

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, templating

I'm trying to build a confirmation window that lists to the user all the changes he has made on a given object.

I have already built eh backend that is simply a `Dictionary<string, IConfirmation>` that lists confirmations that should be made.

However I don't know how to generate a template for each of them that would look like the mockup below, and load them all in a confirmation window after that.

I've already looked at the [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) from msdn but it seems to only template static data (i.e. **no input possible neither embeded control**).

Any idea? Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Would appreciate that if you vote minus, you at least explain the reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect for code since you didn't provide any code to start with :). But `DataTemplate` seems to be the right option for this, in my opinion. The above MSDN link you posted shows exactly how to use `DataTemplate` in detailed, step by step manner. You can just follow what explained there, and change `TextBlocks` to `TextBoxes` or any other input control you want to use. Using input controls shouldn't be an issue for `DataTemplate` as long as you use DataBinding in two way mode.

Comment: I wasn't looking for code, not every question is about getting code done by someone else ;). Thanks for the answer, it was not obvious from the reading that data templating supports inputs, will try further and revert. cheers